# oracle sql TO_CHAR function is adding a trailing blank in some case

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I have a table with a number column that I'm trying to format with the oracle sql function to_char. Depending on how the column is shown, the result get a trailing blank or not.

```
SELECT 
  '[',TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance), 'FM0000000000000000V00'),']',
  '[' || TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance),'FM0000000000000000V00') || ']'
FROM Accounts
```

will get me the following result :

```
[;000000000749460366 ;];[000000000749460366]
[;000000008751094792 ;];[000000008751094792]
[;000000000000050696 ;];[000000000000050696]
[;000000000000000000 ;];[000000000000000000]
```

I would be expecting the same result in both case but I cannot understand why there is a difference. Is there any reason I got these differences ?

Many thanks,
Pierre-Yves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't adding a trailing space to the *value* - if you check the length it's still 18, and if it was then the concatenated version would have a space too. The metadata for the column is deciding the maximum possible length is 19, which seems to be true if the original balance value exceeds 16 digits:

```
set colsep ;
with accounts(balance) as (
  select 749460366 from dual
  union all select 1234567890123456 from dual
  union all select 12345678901234567 from dual
)
SELECT 
  '[',TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance), 'FM0000000000000000V00') as balance,']',
  '[',length(TO_CHAR(Balance, 'FM0000000000000000V00')) as length,']',
  '[' || TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance),'FM0000000000000000V00') || ']'
FROM Accounts;

';BALANCE            ;';';    LENGTH;';'['||TO_CHAR(ABS(BALA
-;-------------------;-;-;----------;-;---------------------
[;000000074946036600 ;];[;        18;];[000000074946036600] 
[;123456789012345600 ;];[;        18;];[123456789012345600] 
[;###################;];[;        19;];[###################]
```

A 17-digit value can't be displayed in the supplied format, and it substitutes hashes; but interestingly 19 of them, however large the balance value actually is.

The `FM` modifier suppresses a leading space for a positive value; but if you had a negative 16-digit value you would still need 19 digits to display it as the minus sign would be present. *You* know the value can't be negative because of the `ABS()` call, but the `TO_CHAR()` function doesn't know that, so it still has to allow for the minus sign in the column width.

If you're really running the query/conversion from an application, e.g. over JDBC, then the string you get back (for less than 17 digits, after the `ABS()`) will be 18 characters and won't have the (non-existent) trailing space.

Your client (or at least, SQL*Plus and SQL Developer) is formatting the column width based on what it thinks the widest possible value can be. You can override that:

```
column balance format A18

with accounts(balance) as (
  select 749460366 from dual
  union all select 1234567890123456 from dual
  union all select 12345678901234567 from dual
  union all select 123456789012345678 from dual
)
SELECT 
  '[',TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance), 'FM0000000000000000V00') as balance,']',
  '[',length(TO_CHAR(Balance, 'FM0000000000000000V00')) as length,']',
  '[' || TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance),'FM0000000000000000V00') || ']'
FROM Accounts;

';BALANCE           ;';';    LENGTH;';'['||TO_CHAR(ABS(BALA
-;------------------;-;-;----------;-;---------------------
[;000000074946036600;];[;        18;];[000000074946036600] 
[;123456789012345600;];[;        18;];[123456789012345600] 
[;##################;];[;        19;];[###################]
 ;#                 ; ; ;          ; ;                     

[;##################;];[;        19;];[###################]
 ;#                 ; ; ;          ; ;
```

... which makes the non-space disappear, but messes up even more if/when the original value exceeds 16 digits as it wraps the extra hash onto the next line.

You could also explicitly CAST the result to the length you expect:

```
clear columns

with accounts(balance) as (
  select 749460366 from dual
  union all select 1234567890123456 from dual
  union all select 12345678901234567 from dual
  union all select 123456789012345678 from dual
)
SELECT 
  '[',CAST(TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance), 'FM0000000000000000V00') as varchar2(18)) as balance,']',
  '[',length(TO_CHAR(Balance, 'FM0000000000000000V00')) as length,']',
  '[' || TO_CHAR(ABS(Balance),'FM0000000000000000V00') || ']'
FROM Accounts;

';BALANCE           ;';';    LENGTH;';'['||TO_CHAR(ABS(BALA
-;------------------;-;-;----------;-;---------------------
[;000000074946036600;];[;        18;];[000000074946036600] 
[;123456789012345600;];[;        18;];[123456789012345600] 
[;##################;];[;        19;];[###################]
[;##################;];[;        19;];[###################]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  '[', lpad(ABS(Balance),18,0) ,']',
  '[' || lpad(ABS(Balance),18,0) || ']'
FROM Accounts
```

this shows me same result.